# Breqn and wrapfig incompatibilitiy

Tags: wrapfigure, breqn

Hello I finally arrived to this awesome place :) ,

I noticed that `breqn` does not go very well with `wrapfigure`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}               
\usepackage{mathtools}  % Math packages

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{breqn} % better equations

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
  \def\svgwidth{1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{./Figures/ell.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
With gravitational force in z direction:

\begin{dmath*}
    g = 0
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

This produces multiple errors for me using MiKTeX:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. ! Illegal unit of measure (pt
inserted). ! Missing \endcsname inserted. ! TeX capacity exceeded,
sorry [main memory size=3000000].
```

Now in that particular example, if I lower `0.4\linewidth` to `0.2\linewidth`, it works. Also, when I use `\equation` instead of `\dmath`, it works. It seems as if `breqn` doesn't like stuff to float into its equations.

Is there any workaround for this situation? Or could I use something else instead of wrapfigure? I just want my figures to float around in my document without producing error messages. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`breqn` should be considered as an interesting but highly experimental package that is incompatible with virtually everything. It's probably not robust enough for use in a production setting.

However you can hide it in a minipage here so it isn't confused by `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}               
\usepackage{mathtools}  % Math packages

\usepackage{wrapfig}


\usepackage{breqn} % better equations

\begin{document}



\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
  \def\svgwidth{1cm}
  \rule{\linewidth}{2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
With gravitational force in z direction:


\noindent\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
\begin{dmath*}
    g = 0
\end{dmath*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```